# how to modularize html page elements using php

Tags: php, html, include

I want to modularize html page elements using PHP. This is the code I am currently using:

```
<?php include("template.php"); 

echo "Hello";?>
```

The template.php actually also includes the body of original html page, inside of which I wish to write "Hello". So will I have to create 3 different PHP templates: 1 for header, 1 for navigation, and 1 for footer and then include them at appropriate locations in a new PHP file or is there any other way out?

Comment: You could include the template.php with header, footer and body in the form of functions... Then use these functions wherever needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could include the 3 files on each page?

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<?php include("navigation.php"); ?>
Hello
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

You could also include the navigation.php inside the header.php

Answer (score 0):

How about using a template engine?
If you want to have same complex layout for multiple pages with some variations on the datasources a template engine would be of real help.
Some good template engines for php are:

1. Smarty http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyFrequentlyAskedQuestions
2. Mustache PHP https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php
3. PHP TAL http://phptal.org/

Of course if you just want some simple header and footer - use include_once as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the `include_once()` function to include the scripts you want to insert and place the code into html `<div></div>` tags so you can display wherever you need them to display in the web page.

```
<div>
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
</div>
<div>
<?php include_once("body.php")?>
</div>    
<div>
<?php include_once("footer.php")?>
</div>
```

Comment: Surrounding div's are actually a bad practice. Your layout should not depend on empty divs